# get some elements in Json array

Tags: javascript

I have a json array format

```
[
  {
    "code": "string",
    "codeB": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "industry": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "nameB": "string"
  }
]
```

I would create a new object with only some items:

```
[
  {
    "code": "string",
    "codeB": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "nameB": "string"
  }
]
```

I get data from localStorage then I do a filter on Items that I need

```
  var allData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("groups"));
  var datafiltered = allData.filter(function(el) {
    return el.code && el.name && el.codeB && el.nameB;
  });
  console.log("data filtered", datafiltered);
```

Actually as a result I get empty array

Comment: Your filter condition will always return false, hence the empty array. if you need to use the same array and delete other unused fields, then use Delete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new Object Array

```
var datafiltered = allData.map(function (el) {
    return {
        code: el.code,
        name: el.name,
        codeB: el.codeB,
        nameB: el.nameB,
    }
});
```

```js
var allData = [{
  "code": "string",
  "codeB": "string",
  "country": "string",
  "industry": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "nameB": "string"
}];

var datafiltered = allData.map(function(el) {
  return {
    code: el.code,
    name: el.name,
    codeB: el.codeB,
    nameB: el.nameB,
  }
});

console.log(datafiltered)
```

Answer (score 4):

For getting some keys only, you could map these properties for a new object.

```js
var data = [{ code: "string", codeB: "string", country: "string", industry: "string", name: "string", nameB: "string" }],
    keys = ['code', 'codeB', 'name', 'nameB'],
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using lodash **[_.pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pick)** function:

```js
const test = [{
  "code": "string",
  "codeB": "string",
  "country": "string",
  "industry": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "nameB": "string"
}];

const keys = ['code', 'codeB', 'name', 'nameB'];

console.log(_.pick(test[0], keys));
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I discover _.pick function